# What is the correct way of storing application data in an Angular 2.0 app?

Tags: javascript, angular

In learning Angular 2, I've seen multiple examples where application data is stored in services.

For example: in a todo-list app, you'd find a "todo" service that would define a "todo entries" list that would become accessible to any consumer of that service.

**My question is:**  Is there a better way of defining application data?  Should it be separated from services?

In my particular case, I'd like to make use of localstorage to save a bunch of application data.  Eventually, I might refactor this to instead save and load data from a database.  Would it make more sense for me to be creating some sort of "data-storage" service that could be used by other services to save and retrieve data, or should data always live with the service that uses it?  How might one choose to structure this in the "todo" example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage is only for improving user experience (caching for speed, or similar) but it's not a place to persist data that must not be lost. For this case you need a server where you can send the data to and which stores it in a database. https://www.firebase.com/ might be convenient for a start.

It is a good idea to separate data from the service that fetches or persists these data. If you use Angulars `Http` service to fetch and persist data from/to a server, this might be separation enough though. When your application becomes more complex you probably want more abstraction but this would need a more concrete example of what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: I definitely understand - I'm simply using localstorage as a convenience while I learn the ropes of Angular 2.  I'm toying around with making a little game that saves player data and some game-state information to local-storage, so it's not a big deal if the data doesn't persist - it's just a little experiment to help me learn Angular 2.

Comment: Sure, it's just fine to use it that way. So does this answer your question?

Comment: Could you briefly describe how you might organize the data and service using an example (such as the todo-list in my original post)?  A concrete example would be really helpful here I think.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an idea what a good example would be. I never reasoned how a todo application should look like. Did you have a look at the hero tutorials at http://angular.io ?

Comment: Yes, I've gone through the hero tutorials.  Perhaps I should make a new post with a more specific example.  I purposefully tried to keep this question somewhat generic, as I was interested moreso in the organization and application design choices that might be made when creating a simple app, and not any specific example.  I'll leave the question open for a while longer in case someone else wants to chime in, however, if there aren't any other answers, I'll mark yours as the solution.

Comment: Specific questions are definitely better here on StackOverflow. Generic questions are often strongly opinionated which is rather discouraged. This is probably why your question got a close vote already.

Comment: Is there a better place to ask high-level questions that are geared more towards architectural and design considerations?  I don't post too often on Stackoverflow, but I tend to see these sorts of questions answered quite frequently - often with very in-depth answers that garner hundreds or thousands of votes.

Comment: [Gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/angular), [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular). Please consider that high-level questions are often hard to understand. Concrete examples usually encourage people more to respond. Developers are problem solvers at first and not always philosophers ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll try re-posting with a more specific example, and perhaps save the generic stuff for elsewhere.